# Resolving host for long time when first connect to home router

Tags: router, wireless-router

I just moved into a new house and when I open my laptop after being closed for a while, my web browser won't connect to any sites for about 3 minutes or so. Any web request says, "resolving host" and times out.

Other apps, such as mail, IRC, torrents etc, connect immediately.

This only happens on my home internet connection and it's pretty annoying.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: If all other apps are able to connect immediately than it almost certain that your browser is the one with the issue (you should change your tags as this does not seem to be related to the router). You did not say what browser you use. Try the same with different browsers and try every one of them in private/incognito mode to see if you have the same behaviour. What happens if you close and reopen the browser? (All browsers have the option to reopen the pages you had open when closed - a feature I use heavily).

Comment: I mentioned that this only happens at home, and not with any other connections anywhere. This leads me to think that is related to either the router or the ISP

Comment: Okay. Anyways, did you test my suggestions? Just to get more info.